# ios - failing app store ipv6 but can't re-produce

Tags: ios, react-native, app-store, ipv6

I have an app that is developed in React Native and uses an API to handle all of the data. The app has already been approved with no problems and no crashing.

I have (after WWDC) recently done some updates to the app and tested everything locally as well on a real device. The app works fine with no crashing at all.

Apple have come back with the following response:

> "Performance - 2.1 Your app crashed on iPad and iPhone running iOS
>   10.2 connected to an IPv6 network when we: 1. Launched app 2. Tapped"

The issue is that I cannot replicate the issue happening on my local machine (we use ipv4 at our offices) and the server is not IPv6.

I did some research and as of WWDC (2015), apps cannot be released into the store unless their APIS are on IPv6 server. However, I'm struggling to understand why this would cause the app to crash as it does work fine on my machine and on my device.

Is there a way that I can replicate the issue that apple are having? And could the issue that Apple are having be because of the IPv6 issue?

Comment: I think this will help your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38783443/react-native-app-store-rejection-support-for-ipv6

Comment: You already told that your server not supporting IPv6. Your server should support IPv6 alone connections.

Comment: @MidhunMP No. I contacted the server team where its hosted whom said that converting to IPv6 is not an easy task and not something they'd be willing to do without us creating a new server

Comment: Apple has instructions on how to test on an IPv6-only network, and how to create a test network.

Comment: Your server doesn't need to support IPv6, but it is highly recommended to support it. Without IPv6 support on the server the client needs to go through translation services that can be overloaded and slow. Connections also time out much quicker. By supporting IPv6 on both the server and client side you can avoid this mess and give your users optimal service.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. Then figured out that my app did not handle the scenario when the push notification permissions were rejected by the user. So it is best to check if you are prompting users for any permission (when app initially start) and see if the app behaves as expected when these permission are **Rejected**. (My guess is that testers at apple usually declines these permission when they are testing)